# Does this rhythm have a name?

Tags: rhythm

Does the following rhythm have a recognised name or composer?

It is a rhythm you would typically hear at Soccer matched with the crowd clapping in time with each other.  At an England match you would hear the crowd shout "Eng-Land" with the last quaver and crotchet.

[image]

Comment: Music Fans may get more response.

Comment: Just like “shave and a haircut, two bits”, the famous door knock rhythm, it’s probably a rhythm from a song, I would guess something contemporary. Hopefully someone will recognize the source..

Comment: This rhythm used in _The Cars, Let's Go_ and _Ramones, Rock and Roll Radio_, but I don't know of a name for the rhythm.

Comment: @Tim, this seems a fair question. Some rhythms have well known names like habanera, tresillo, bolero, etc.

Comment: I can attest to it being used as far back as the 60s/70's at Leeds Utd matches. "M. I. MIC. M.I.C.K.Mick Jones"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if this is definitive, but I did some tracing back to the 1962 song *Let's Go (Pony)* by The Routers.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Go_(Pony)

So, there may not be a name for it, but I think this is a reasonable pop culture source. It's interesting to note the connection to sports cheerleading.

Comment: Good find Michael! Not surprising it’s been used in other songs, it’s a catchy rhythm..and short enough to not infringe on a copyright. +1

Answer (score 1):

Used by Bay City Rollers - Saturday Night

Answer (score -3):

The last 5 beats are "shave and a haircut, two bits." It can be tacked on to most songs.

Comment: If you substitute two sixteenths for the second 8th note of the second bar it would be that exactly.

Comment: Isn't shave and a haircut in 6/8?

Comment: It's in 4/4: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shave_and_a_Haircut

Comment: It seems that @MichaelCurtis answer is the correct one.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - definitely in 4/4.

Comment: @Aaron and Tim, notice what it says about the triplet feel on beat two. That's how I know it.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis Tim and Aaron check out “At a Darktown Cakewalk” https://youtu.be/LHhZbkEMmUM written in 1899 in 2/4 time. Hot Scotch Rag uses the same figure. Originally there was one less note, the note for the word “and” wasn’t there. Also the melody note that is the 6th was originally a b6. There have been many variations over the years and there was a question about it here a while back as well.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis Yes, I see now. From Wikipedia: "In a variation on this tune, the second and third notes are replaced with a triplet with the middle a semitone lower, and the fourth note is flatted." Not that you've pointed it out, I recognize I've heard it that way, too.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy [Question a while back](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/4889/where-does-this-famous-rhythm-pattern-come-from-oftenly-used-to-knock-on-a-door)